# Escape space in linux Commands

Tags: linux, bash

I want to replace space in linux commands with something else.
For example:

```
echo "test"     --->      echo\040"test"
```

i know \040 is not working but i am looking for a proper replacement.

Comment: What is the context? In general, you cannot change what the parser uses for initially parsing the command line.

Comment: @LucM I have a limited service and i am able to pass only limited keywords with parameter. for example ping x.x.x.x i tried and  found it is vulnerable to mixed input. for example ping x.x.x.x&ls will do ping and list the current directory. i am a pen-tester and i want to complete my observation ,i need to ensure how much would be dangerous this vulnerability. for example is user able to modify or add and execute a file? user (intruder) have to change the command(s) to a no space command because it seems the command parser is sensitive to space.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot do this. The shell parser works roughly as follows:

1. Split the line into words based on blanks alone (spaces and tabs).
2. Apply expansion to each of the initial set of words.
3. Identify the command to run and execute it.

Your problem is that you want to change how words are identified in step 1; you can't do this.

---

In certain contexts, you can use `eval` to execute a pre-parsed command. For example:

```
cmd="echo,foo"
IFS=,
eval $cmd
```

This outputs `foo` because when unquoted `$cmd` is expanded, it produces two space-separated words after word-splitting, `echo` and `foo`. This is then executed by `eval`, producing the desired result. However, it is *strongly* recommended you not write code like this in practice, as it is easy to execute code you did not intend to with `eval`.

---

For the example you give (the user inputting `ping x.x.x.x`), you should do something like this. Instead of executing the input as code, you treat it as a request to execute code your script provides.

```
read cmd argument
case $cmd in
    ping) ping "$argument" ;;
    *) printf 'Unrecognized command "%s"\n' "$cmd" >&2 ;;
esac
```

Now, there is no arbitrary execution. No matter what the user enters, your script either executes `ping` with a *single* argument, or your script prints an error message.

Comment: I have a limited service and i am able to pass only limited keywords with parameter. for example ping x.x.x.x i tried and i found it is vulnerable to mixed input. for example ping x.x.x.x&ls will do ping and list the current directory. also about ping x.x.x.x&cat</var/log/... i am a pen-tester and i want to complete my observation ,i need to ensure how much would be dangerous this vulnerability. for example is user able to modify or add and execute a file? user (intruder) have to change the command(s) to a no space command because it seems the command parser is sensitive to space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try other whitespace than space. Tab, CR, LF, ...

If it runs directly in bash, you can use the defined shell variables :

```
echo$IFS"test"
```

Or escape your command with a c-like string and run that one:

```
$(cat<<<$'echo\x20test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chepner's insight I'm now sure it's impossible as long as you need to pass a parameter (since you will have to separate the command from the parameter by a space). However if you don't (i.e. if the parameter is always the same), you could make a script or a function that would execute code containing spaces, which could be invoked without using space.

Comment: Yes, this already has a space! i need a alternative that not contain any space!!

Comment: Oh ! Then Mark Plotnik's comment is what will suit you. I'll rework my answer to expand on it.

Comment: No, Mark's comment does not help in this case: try `IFS=,` followed by `echo,foo`. You'll get a "command not found" error, instead of printing "foo".

Comment: @chepner that's what I was currently trying, isn't it supposed to work though? or is the IFS usage limited to a certain set of functionnality?

Comment: The parser first breaks the line into words based on whitespace; `IFS` is only used for word-splitting in the later phases of expanding the line before finally executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you expected

```
$cat j
echo "test"
```

replacing space with newline

```
$ cat j|sed -e 's/\s/\xC/'g
echo
    "test"
```